# Rebasing pushed commits if only on personal branch

Tags: git, git-rebase

I use multiple machines for my development, so want a way of "self-collaborating". So a personal branch on the remote repository makes sense. Obviously for this branch I would be pushing/pulling a lot (i.e. everytime I start/finish a coding session on a particular machine). I also like to rebase locally to squash/tidyup some of my commits. I understand that you shouldn't rebase commits that have been pushed to the remote repository. However, are there any problems with me rebasing commits that also exist on the server if they only exist in my private branch (noone else touches this branch)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, git does not really have problem with this. In fact, git's own development process involves a branch on the public server that is rebased quite often (like every day or so). As long as everybody using the branch knows it is being rebased frequently, it's OK.

However you need to remember that you'll have old and new version of the patch without clear indication which supersedes which. Which you can probably easily solve by force-pushing the branch back when you rebase it and thus dropping the old version altogether.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a local branch that you push regularly to a remote repo, but that nobody will use directly (i.e. won't checkout to or merge from your cloned branch), then it is OK to rebase your local branch as many time as you want/need.

But that supposes a good naming convention to identify such "private branches".
And that also supposes you have the right to do a forced push (push -f) in order to override your own history (of the remote private branch) with the rewritten history of your local (private) branch.
That last point isn't obvious, since shared repo often disable that kind of push to avoid "accident" (unless you have some kind of ACL management like [Gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite))

Comment: Shared repo does not disable force-push without it's administrator explicitly installing the hook (which is provided as sample, but still has to be made executable manually) or using some tool (like Gitolite) to do it.

Comment: @Jan: a/ hence the word "often", b/ you don't need any hook or executable or Gitolite to disable it: `git config receive.denyNonFastForwards true` is enough. +1 to your answer btw (I didn't see it at the time)

Comment: I'm using Gitolite and am the administrator. So I can do a forced push, and also I can enforce the private permissions of my own branch to stop anyone else accidentally using it. The naming convention of this branch is quite obviously too. Good point to mention though.